# How to append / extend zshell completions?

Tags: ssh, zsh, autocomplete, hostname, oh-my-zsh

I am using zsh with oh-my-zsh. Unfortunately, oh-my-zsh does not use file `~/.ssh/config` for hostname auto-completion (see [Issue #1009](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1009), for instance).

This could easily archived by the following code:

```
[ -r ~/.ssh/config ] && _ssh_config=($(cat ~/.ssh/config | sed -ne 's/Host[=\t ]//p')) || _ssh_config=()
zstyle ':completion:*:hosts' hosts $_ssh_config
```

However, if I add the above commands to my `~/.zshrc` file, all other sources for hostnames (like `~/.ssh/known_hosts`), which are defined in file `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh`, are overridden.

How can I *append* new completion rules for `':completion:*:hosts'` in my `~/.zshrc` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to retrieve the existing items and append yours.

```
zstyle -s ':completion:*:hosts' hosts _ssh_config
[[ -r ~/.ssh/config ]] && _ssh_config+=($(cat ~/.ssh/config | sed -ne 's/Host[=\t ]//p'))
zstyle ':completion:*:hosts' hosts $_ssh_config
```

Comment: Thanks, `zstyle -s` was the missing piece.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to redefine the *hosts* command (by default `getent hosts`) using `zstyle`s. The advantage is that you can do it for `ssh` only and make it dynamic (except for the caching done by the completion system):

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:ssh*:*:hosts' command '
  getent hosts; sed -n "s/^Host[=[:blank:]]*/ignored /p" ~/.ssh/config'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option appears be to just use zsh's defaults.

See my pull request for oh-my-zsh at https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/1498

Answer (score 0):

You may want to replace oh-my-zsh with the much-better written and maintained https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto which uses default zsh completions and this external module https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions